# How to use a question "What are you"?

Tags: spoken-english, non-standard-english

I was looking through some English books and I found that in a dialogue one person ask another

> "What are you?"

And answer was

> "I'm policeman."

I first time saw this way to ask about occupation. Can this question be used in this sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a little rude to me, but then it is out of context.

The most common way to ask someone their profession is:

> What do you do?

or the slightly longer

> What do you do for a living?

Asking "*what are you*?" seems rude because in isolation it is not clear that you are asking about a person's profession. It could be misinterpreted as bringing into question someone's worth or validity.

But there could be contexts in which "*what are you*" would be just fine if certain other things have already been established in the conversation.

For example:

> Person 1: My colleague in the police force has just been promoted to Chief Inspector.
>   Person 2: What are you?
>   Person 1: I'm a Chief Superintendent.

This doesn't seem as rude because it has already been established that the two people are talking about roles or job titles and the question is now drawing a comparison between two different roles.

Comment: Apparently "what do you do" meaning "what do you do for a living?" is location specific, and some people even get upset about Americans using it this way (since it supposedly indicates that we're status-obsessed).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, albeit phrased like this it seems to be something a child might ask, and it is still quite vague and subject to misinterpretation.

A better way of asking  might be (casual):

> "What do you do for a living?"

Or (more formal):

> "What's your occupation?"

Comment: Is 'What's your job?' OK?

Comment: @Ashna Yes!  Also.  :)